# Can someone find the error in calculating number of 1's in binary representation?

Tags: c, debugging, error-handling

This code is outputting 0 for all values other 1. For 1 it is outputting 1. It looks like it is the executing the else statement because "temp" value is not being printed (All extra print statements have been added for debugging). Please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int binarysum(long long int p);
int main(){
    int r;
    long long int x;
    scanf("%lld",&x);
    r=binarysum(x);
    printf("%d",r);
    return 0;
}
int binarysum(long long int p){
    int result;
    int j;
    long long int check=pow(2,30),temp;
    printf("%lld p %lld check\n",p,check);
    if(p==0)
        result=0;
    else if(p==1)
        result=1;
    else{
        for(j=31;j>=2;j--){
            temp=check/2;
            if(p>=temp){
                printf("%lld temp\n",temp);
                result=1+binarysum(p-temp);
                break;
            }
        } 
    }
    printf("%d result\n",result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: First thought is that temp is the same every time in your for loop, since check is never changed.

Comment: Your bracketing is wrong; that is you have one more `}` in your snippet than `{`. I'm not sure if you left out code, or simply put one too many `}` before your `printf("%d result\n, result);` line. Either way, this is why you should properly indent your code.

Comment: No, he has the correct number of brackets, 5 of each. The indentation just makes it hard to tell.

Comment: Where's the fifth `{`? I see one in front of `main`, one in front of `binarysum`, one in front of the `else` and one in front of the `for`.

Comment: Ah... the `if`. Never mind, then.

Comment: Most convoluted way of calculating a popcount ever?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790580/can-someone-find-the-error-in-calculating-number-of-1s-in-binary-representation#comment38475711_24790580 is the correct answer. It should really be promoted to an answer.

Comment: @Mike Precup Thanks a lot, it work justs fine now. :)

Comment: @MSN Alright, I'll make an answer. Didn't want to make an answer without having a chance to test it, but if it's working, sweet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `check` is never updated in the for loop.

```
for(j=31;j>=2;j--){
    temp=check/2;
    if(p>=temp){
        printf("%lld temp\n",temp);
        result=1+binarysum(p-temp);
        break;
    }
}
```

`temp` is set using check every time, but since `check` doesn't change, neither does `temp`.
Either switch it to `temp /= 2;`, or use `check` instead of `temp`.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to calculate a population count on a binary number?
What's wrong with

```
int popcount(unsigned long long a)
{
    int retval = 0;
    size_t i;
    unsigned long long b = 1;
    for (i = 0; i<(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(unsigned long long); i++)
    {
        if (a & b<<i)
           retval++;
    }
    return retval;
}
```

If you should find this too slow, you could go with the appropriate section of "bit twiddling hacks" (google it yourself, or search on this site).
Or, you know, look up compiler intrinsics that do it in one cycle. Intel x86(-64):

```
int64_t _mm_popcnt_u64(unsigned __int64 a);
```

gcc:

```
int __builtin_popcountll(unsigned long long)
```

Answer (score 1):

pow is a floating-point function. So apart from being horrifically slow, pow (2, 30) may have rounding errors that make it a bit smaller than 2 raised to the power of 30, and assigning it to a long long will round it down to 0x3fffffff instead of 0x40000000. On the other hand, (1ll << 30) will be evaluated at compile time, and is guaranteed to give the correct result.

check is never modified in the loop, which is why it doesn't work.

How many bits would you say are set in the number -1?

How many bits would you say are set in the number 1234567890123456? Why wouldn't you give the right result for that number?

I'd say you need a bit of practice to find the most direct and simplest way to solve a problem.

```
int bitcount = 0; 
for (long long mask = 1ll << 62; mask != 0; mask >>= 1)
    if ((p & mask) != 0)
        ++bitcount;
```

That's the straightforward way to do it. You should really use unsigned, not signed for that kind of operation. There are clever tricks that give you faster code, but not what I would expect anyone to figure out on their own.

Comment: Round-off errors in `pow(2, 30)` are impossible. Also, I see no reason for asking "how many bits" for -1 and 1234567890123456. (good code though, so didn't downvote)

Answer (score 0):

The main error is that your recursive function is not working.
Try to take a close look:

```
if(p==0)
    result=0;
        else if(p==1)
    result=1;
else{
    for(j=31;j>=2;j--){
        temp=check/2;
        printf("temp=%lld\n",temp);
        if(p>=temp){
            printf("%lld temp\n",temp);
            result=1+binarysum(p-temp);
        }
    }
}
```

If suppose p=6 then your temp is 2^30 clearly p is less than temp. So your recursion doesn't work.
The statement:

```
result=1+binarysum(p-temp);
```

never executes. So you get `result` as zero because zero is the garbage value stored in the variable `result`.
if you change your code to:

```
else{
    temp=check;
    for(j=31;j>=2;j--){
        temp=temp/2;
        printf("temp=%lld\n",temp);
        if(p>=temp){
            printf("%lld temp\n",temp);
            result=1+binarysum(p-temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is easy way to solve your problem

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    long long number;
    scanf("%lld",&number);
    int result=0;
    while(number>0){
        if(number&1){
            result++;
        }
        number=number>>1;
    }
    printf("%d\n",result);
}
```

Comment: Note: i edited the misleading expression `number&1==1`

Comment: its correct both ways. The main reason I wrote number&1==1 to emphasize that `bitwise and` returns the last digit in binary representation of a number.